# Unable to start AKKA application inside docker container

Tags: scala, docker, akka, akka-http, akka-remote-actor

I am attempting to start an akka application inside a docker container.

Following is a snippet from the application.conf

```
    akka.persistence.journal.plugin = "akka.persistence.journal.leveldb"
    akka.persistence.snapshot-store.plugin = "akka.persistence.snapshot-store.local"
    akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.native = true
    akka.persistence.snapshot-store.local.dir = "data/snapshots"
    akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.dir = "data/journal"
```

logingestordev          | java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load library. Reasons: [no leveldbjni64-1.8 in java.library.path, no leveldbjni-1.8 in java.library.path, no leveldbjni in java.library.path, Permission denied]
logingestordev          |   at org.fusesource.hawtjni.runtime.Library.doLoad(Library.java:182)
logingestordev          |   at org.fusesource.hawtjni.runtime.Library.load(Library.java:140)
logingestordev          |   at org.fusesource.leveldbjni.JniDBFactory.(JniDBFactory.java:48)
logingestordev          |   at akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.LeveldbStore$class.leveldbFactory(LeveldbStore.scala:52)
logingestordev          |   at akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.LeveldbJournal.leveldbFactory(LeveldbJournal.scala:23)
logingestordev          |   at akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.LeveldbStore$class.preStart(LeveldbStore.scala:178)
logingestordev          |   at akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.LeveldbJournal.preStart(LeveldbJournal.scala:23)
logingestordev          |   at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundPreStart(Actor.scala:522)
logingestordev          |   at akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.LeveldbJournal.aroundPreStart(LeveldbJournal.scala:23)
logingestordev          |   at akka.actor.ActorCell.create(ActorCell.scala:591)
logingestordev          |   at akka.actor.ActorCell.invokeAll$1(ActorCell.scala:462)

I am not running this application as the 'root' user, inside the docker container. Inside the DockerFile, I also have the following lines of code, to run it as a particular user

```
    RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash portal-admin
    USER portal-admin
    WORKDIR /home/portal-admin
    RUN chown portal-admin /home/portal-admin
```

This is on a 'centos:6.9' image.

Comment: Need to set JVM property `java.library.path` to directory including the required native lib mentioned in the error

Comment: Are you building your application properly? Are you using sbt-native-packager?

Comment: @Shankar Shastri I am not using 'sbt-native-packager'. I am using 'gradle' to build this project.


@cchantep 
I did copy the ".so" file to one of the directories from java.library.path 

    `public static void main(String args[]){ 
                System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path")); 
    }` 

Not sure what the "Permission Denied" error means. Does it mean that it cannot access any of the paths set in java.library.path

Comment: @ArvindI Can you share the repo?

Comment: Eventually, I was able to get the container to run. I set the native flag to 'false' and forced it to use the libraries instead of native (.so) version of levelDB

`akka.persistence.journal.leveldb.native = false`